# 正規表現を使って、nofollowを取得したいです。

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

様々なURLからbeutifulsoupを利用しHTMLソース上から、`example.com`の発リンクに対して`rel=nofollow`がついているものだけを抽出したいです。

VBAしか利用したことがなく、こんな感じかなと思いますがご指摘いただければ幸いです。

```
df = re.findall("http.*?" & example.com & ".*?rel=(.*?)>", soup)
```

Comment: まずは実際の取得対象となるURLをいくつか載せてみてください。その中で、これは該当して欲しい、これは該当して欲しくないという例があると早く回答が付くと思いますよ。

Answer (score 1):

今ある情報からだけで判断すると以下のような感じかな？と思います。
a tag中のhrefに設定されてるURLから該当するものをhitさせる正規表現です。

```
(?<=href=['"])https?://example.com/.*rel=nofollow.*(?=['"])
```